# How to create an inverse ordered variable in my sql

Tags: mysql

I have a column with running sum, but I would like to inverse the order in a new or same column

My Query is

```
SELECT date,
ant, 
num_room,
(@csum:= @csum + num_room) as cumulative_room
from xxx_xxxx_xxxx
WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
AND(select @csum := 0) = 0
order by date
```

Mi table is

```
 date         | ant  | num_room  | cumulative_room
    28-04-2020       6       1              1  
    28-04-2020       3       1              2
    28-04-2020       4       1              3
    28-04-2020       7       1              4
    28-04-2020       4       1              5
    ....
```

How I can do another variable with reverse order from cumulative_room?

```
 date         | ant  | num_room  | cumulative_room |reverse_cumulative room
28-04-2020       6       1              1                5
28-04-2020       3       1              2                4
28-04-2020       4       1              3                3
28-04-2020       7       1              4                2
28-04-2020       4       1              5                1
    ....
```

Comment: Easy in MySQL 8.x. Are you using MySQL 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: I am using MYSQL 5.6.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your complete code is

```
SELECT
t1.*
, t2.max_room - `cumulative_room` 'reverse_cumulative room'
FROm (SELECT date,
                ant, 
                num_room,
                (@csum:= @csum + num_room) as cumulative_room
                from xxx_xxxx_xxxx
                WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
                AND(select @csum := 0) = 0
                order by date) t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(`cumulative_room`) +1 max_room,  `date` FROM (SELECT date,
                                                                            ant, 
                                                                            num_room,
                                                                            (@csum:= @csum + num_room) as cumulative_room
                                                                            from xxx_xxxx_xxxx
                                                                            WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
                                                                            AND(select @csum := 0) = 0
                                                                            order by date) t3 GROUP BY  `date`) t2
ON t1.`date` = t2.`date`;
```

The idea behind this is

> ```
> CREATE TABLE xxx_xxxx_xxxx (
>   `date` VARCHAR(10),
>   `ant` INTEGER,
>   `num_room` INTEGER,
>   `cumulative_room` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO xxx_xxxx_xxxx
>   (`date`, `ant`, `num_room`, `cumulative_room`)
> VALUES
>   ('28-04-2020', '6', '1', '1'),
>   ('28-04-2020', '3', '1', '2'),
>   ('28-04-2020', '4', '1', '3'),
>   ('28-04-2020', '7', '1', '4'),
>   ('28-04-2020', '4', '1', '5');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> t1.*
> ,t2.max_room - `cumulative_room` 'reverse_cumulative room'
> FROm xxx_xxxx_xxxx t1
> INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(`cumulative_room`) +1 max_room,  `date` FROM xxx_xxxx_xxxx GROUP BY  `date`) t2
> ON t1.`date` = t2.`date`;
> ```
>
> ```
> date       | ant | num_room | cumulative_room | reverse_cumulative room
> :--------- | --: | -------: | --------------: | ----------------------:
> 28-04-2020 |   6 |        1 |               1 |                       5
> 28-04-2020 |   3 |        1 |               2 |                       4
> 28-04-2020 |   4 |        1 |               3 |                       3
> 28-04-2020 |   7 |        1 |               4 |                       2
> 28-04-2020 |   4 |        1 |               5 |                       1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c656d843c6667eb783416f867aa830a3)*

Comment: thank you for you response. I do not why, but I have a error "[mysqld-5.6.40]Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: thanks again, now I have tried to order by ant, where I would like to get reverse_cumulative room by ant.

Comment: i don't understand you tried to sort the code from your question or the result from mine?

Comment: I had to change in my code with subquery and I have the same question

Comment: Write a fiddle like in my post and we will see what can be done