# How to calculate reverse running sum in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, window-functions

I have this query where I calculated cumulative sum. Now, I need to calculate reverse cumulative sum for the same variable

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.ant, t1.hab,  
(@csum:= @csum + t1.hab) as cumulative_hab
from(
SELECT date,
        ant, 
        sum(num_habit) as hab
        from xxxxxxxxxx
        WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY AND CURDATE()
        group by ant) AS t1
,(select @csum := 0) vars
order by t1.ant
```

My table look like this

```
date       ant   hab    cumulative_hab
24-05-2020  0   382,000   382,000
24-05-2020  1   28,000    410,000
24-05-2020  2   26,000    436,000
24-05-2020  3   11,000    447,000
24-05-2020  4   29,000    476,000
24-05-2020  6   6,000     482,000
24-05-2020  7   12,000    494,000
28-05-2020  8   50,000    544,000
24-05-2020  12  5,000     549,000
24-05-2020  13  6,000     555,000
```

I would like another column with reverse running sum (reverse cumulative sum), the first value is calculated 555 - 382

```
 date      ant   hab    cumulative_hab   reverse_cum_hab
24-05-2020  0   382,000   382,000             555,000
24-05-2020  1   28,000    410,000             173,000, 
24-05-2020  2   26,000    436,000             145,000
24-05-2020  3   11,000    447,000             119,000
24-05-2020  4   29,000    476,000             108,000
24-05-2020  6   6,000     482,000              79,000
24-05-2020  7   12,000    494,000              73,000
28-05-2020  8   50,000    544,000              61,000
24-05-2020  12  5,000     549,000              11,000
24-05-2020  13  6,000     555,000               6,000
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62071686/how-to-create-an-inverse-ordered-variable-in-my-sql

Comment: I am using MYSQL 5.6.4

Comment: How is this different from your previous question which you accepted an answer to?

Comment: is a bit different because my code changed (more dates and sum(x)) , I tried to use your response but I could not do it with this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a starter: if you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this easily with window functions:

```
select 
    date,
    ant,
    sum(num_habit) as hab,
    sum(sum(num_habit)) over(order by date) cumulative_hab,
    sum(sum(num_habit)) over(order by date desc) reverse_cumulative_hab
from mytable
where date between current_date - interval 5 day and current_date
group by date, ant
order by date
```

In earlier versions, it is more complicated. I would suggest joining two queries:

```
select t.*, r.reverse_cumulative_hab
from (
    select t.*, @csum := @csum + hab cumulative_hab
    from (
        select date, ant, sum(num_habit) as hab
        from mytable
        where date between current_date - interval 5 day and current_date
        group by date, ant
        order by date
    ) t
    cross join (select @csum := 0) x
) t
inner join (
    select t.*, @rcsum := @rcsum + hab reverse_cumulative_hab
    from (
        select date, ant, sum(num_habit) as hab
        from mytable
        where date between current_date - interval 5 day and current_date
        group by date, ant
        order by date desc
    ) t
    cross join (select @rcsum := 0) x
) r on r.date = t.date
order by t.date
```

This assumes no duplicate `ant` per `date`.

It might also be possible to simplify the logic and compute the reverse sum by taking the difference between the cumulative sum and the overall sum:

```
select t.*, z.total_hab - t.cumulative_hab reverse_cumulative_hab
from (
    select t.*, @csum := @csum + hab cumulative_hab
    from (
        select date, ant, sum(num_habit) as hab
        from mytable
        where date between current_date - interval 5 day and current_date
        group by date, ant
        order by date
    ) t
    cross join (select @csum := 0) x
) t
cross join (
    select sum(num_habit) as total_hab
    from mytable
    where date between current_date - interval 5 day and current_date
) z
order by date
```

Note that these queries are safer than your original code in regard of ordering of the rows: records are ordered in a subquery *before* the cumulative sum is computed.

Comment: Was thinking the same strategy +1.

Comment: @TheImpaler: thanks. I tried another one that uses the difference with the total (this might be more efficient). Too bad that OP did not provide sample data so I can't test.

Comment: I imagine the OP was disincentivised!

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried with the third code because I have duplicates. I had to make a little change (group by ant, date and order by ant, date) it is working, but the first value (reverse_cumulative_hab) is not the total is the second value and the last value is zero

Comment: Two little changes: group by ant, date and order by ant, date. In the first row add + t.hab (z.total_hab - t.cumulative_hab + t.hab reverse_cumulative_hab )